# How can I count the number of entities that don't have certain attributes grouped by a common attribute in an EAV(ish) schema?

Tags: mysql, count, entity-attribute-value

I'm trying to get a count by region of the number of files that DON'T contain "important" attributes given the following dataset:

```
files
------------------------------------
id | file                  | region
------------------------------------
1  | data.xml              | eastern
2  | 2011-01-01-report.xml | eastern
3  | regional report.xml   | western
4  | data.xml              | central
5  | 2010 summary.xml      | eastern

file_attributes
--------------------------------------------
file_id   | attribute   | value | importance
--------------------------------------------
1         | Patients    | 18    | 0
1         | Deaths      | 17    | 1
2         | Clients     | 5     | 0
3         | Refunds     | 12    | 1
5         | Deaths      | 4     | 1
```

I can get a count of the number of files that have important attributes like this:

```
SELECT
  region
  , COUNT(f.id) AS file_count
  , COUNT(DISTINCT if(fa.importance = 1, f.id)) AS files_w_important_attr
  , COUNT(DISTINCT if(fa.importance = 0, f.id)) AS files_w_unimportant_attr
FROM files AS f
  LEFT JOIN object_attributes AS fa
    ON f.id = fa.object_id
GROUP BY f.region
```

This yields the following results:

```
region  | file_count | files_w_important_attr | files_w_unimportant_attr
------------------------------------------------------------------------
central | 1          | 0                      | 0
eastern | 3          | 2                      | 2
western | 1          | 1                      | 0
```

I'm having trouble figuring out how to get a count of the files without important attributes. Note that I'm not trying to get a count of the files that have unimportant attributes which is what the 3rd column in the above query yields. What I want is the following results:

```
region  | file_count | files_w_important_attr | files_w_NO_important_attr
------------------------------------------------------------------------
central | 1          | 0                      | 1
eastern | 3          | 2                      | 1
western | 1          | 1                      | 0
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

SUM( fa.importance IS NULL ) AS nulledFiles

Comment: That would yield the number of files with unimportant attributes which is a bit different from what I'm looking.